# Is there any point in using the ArrayList class anymore?

Tags: c#, generics, arraylist

I realize that if you are running .NET 1.1, then generics aren't available. But, if you are using .NET 2.0+, then are there any advantages to using the `ArrayList` class over `List<object>`?

Basically, as long as you declare the type *T* as `System.Object`, then why not use the `List<T>` class instead?

Comment: The advantage is `you don't have to type the < and >`, the disadvantage is `it seems to be obsolete soon or later`

Comment: There is no reason, other than to interface with .NET 1.1 code.

Comment: @KingKing Really? That's the advantage you found? ... ?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead `YEAH` :)))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with Daniel.

In addition, however, there is specific performance information from Microsoft on MSDN comparing `List<T>` and `ArrayList` that is worth a read.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx

> In deciding whether to use the List or ArrayList class, both of
>   which have similar functionality, remember that the List class
>   performs better in most cases and is type safe. If a reference type is
>   used for type T of the List class, the behavior of the two classes
>   is identical. However, if a value type is used for type T, you need to
>   consider implementation and boxing issues.
>
> If a value type is used for type T, the compiler generates an
>   implementation of the List class specifically for that value type.
>   That means a list element of a List object does not have to be
>   boxed before the element can be used, and after about 500 list
>   elements are created the memory saved not boxing list elements is
>   greater than the memory used to generate the class implementation.
>
> Make certain the value type used for type T implements the
>   IEquatable generic interface. If not, methods such as Contains must
>   call the Object.Equals(Object) method, which boxes the affected list
>   element. If the value type implements the IComparable interface and
>   you own the source code, also implement the IComparable generic
>   interface to prevent the BinarySearch and Sort methods from boxing
>   list elements. If you do not own the source code, pass an IComparer
>   object to the BinarySearch and Sort methods
>
> It is to your advantage to use the type-specific implementation of the
>   List class instead of using the ArrayList class or writing a
>   strongly typed wrapper collection yourself. The reason is your
>   implementation must do what the .NET Framework does for you already,
>   and the common language runtime can share Microsoft intermediate
>   language code and metadata, which your implementation cannot.

Answer (score 4):

I would not use it for anything new, and I make it a point to factor it out of existing code where it is convenient to do so.  List eliminates much unnecessary type casting, improving performance while reducing the potential for run-time errors.  It is also so prevalent now that most extension methods and libraries will be built for it, rather than ArrayList, making it a better choice even if it were technically on par with ArrayList, which it is not.

Aside from old legacy code, I do not believe .NET would suffer at all if it simply vanished from the library.

Answer (score 0):

List is a much better option where type casting becomes a bigger issue in complex applications